# C++17 std::variant is slower than dynamic polymorphism?

Tags: c++, polymorphism, c++17, std-variant, static-polymorphism

I was following [this blog](https://www.cppstories.com/2020/04/variant-virtual-polymorphism.html/) and was trying to replace a dynamic polymorphism code into using `std::variant` and `std::visit`. But I can not get `std::variant` + `std::visit` to work better than a virtual struct impl. Its about **1.3-1.5x slower!** (GCC 10.3 -O3 C++17)

The use case is as follows. Say we are comparing i'th and j'th row of two tables. A table could have heterogeneously typed columns. Assume we can access column buffers.
What I am doing is testing,

```py
def IndexEqual(Table:A, Table:B, int:i, int:j):
  for c in range(A.num_cols):
     if not A.column(c)[i] == B.column(c)[j]:
         return False
  return True
```

for dynamic polymorphism I have the following for `int` and `float`

```cpp
struct Comp{
  virtual bool comp(size_t i, size_t j) const = 0;
};

struct CompI: public Comp {
  CompI(const int *data_1, const int *data_2) : data1(data_1), data2(data_2) {}

  const int *data1, *data2;
  bool comp(size_t i, size_t j) const override {
    return data1[i] == data2[j];
  }
};

struct CompF: public Comp {
  CompF(const float *data_1, const float *data_2) : data1(data_1), data2(data_2) {}

  const float *data1, *data2;
  bool comp(size_t i, size_t j) const override {
    return data1[i] == data2[j];
  }
};

bool IndexEqual1(const std::vector<Comp *> &comps, size_t i, size_t j) {
  for (auto &&a: comps) {
    if (!a->comp(i, j)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

This was transformed to `std::variant` + `std::visit` as follows.

```cpp
struct EqualToI {
  EqualToI(const int *data_1, const int *data_2) : data1(data_1), data2(data_2) {}
  const int *data1, *data2;
  bool comp(size_t i, size_t j) const {
    return data1[i] == data2[j];
  }
};

struct EqualToF {
  EqualToF(const float *data_1, const float *data_2) : data1(data_1), data2(data_2) {}
  const float *data1, *data2;
  bool comp(size_t i, size_t j) const {
    return data1[i] == data2[j];
  }
};

using var_type = typename std::variant<EqualToI, EqualToF>;

bool IndexEqual(const std::vector<var_type> &comps, size_t i, size_t j) {
  for (auto &&a: comps) {
    if (!std::visit([&](const auto &comp) {
      return comp.comp(i, j);
    }, a)) {
      return false;
    }
  }
  return true;
}
```

I benchmarked this here
https://quick-bench.com/q/u-cBjg4hyQjOs6fKem9XSdW7LMs

**Can someone one please explain why this `std::variant` + `std::visit` option is slower than the dynamic polimorphism approach? I was expecting otherwise!** Is there a problem in my approach and/or benchmark?

Comment: That blog that you are following is not describing static polymorphism.  Try this blog instead: https://mropert.github.io/2017/11/30/polymorphic_ducks/

Comment: There are two ways to implement std::variant, with dynamic dispatch and with magic.

Answer (score 5):

Using `variant` does not constitute "static polymorphism". It is still dynamic polymorphism because the compiler does not know which type will actually inhabit the `variant`. Therefore, the code in question must attempt to figure out what the `variant` stores at runtime, and it must dispatch those calls accordingly.

Note that the article you link to *also* doesn't call it "static polymorphism". It emphasizes that it is merely a different form of "runtime polymorphism" from virtual functions.

Comment: I see. Thank you for the clarification (I changed the title accordingly). Is there a better way I could achieve this?

Comment: @n1r44 So you want a dynamic dispatch implementation that is faster than all known ones, right?

Comment: @n1r44 sure just hand roll your own dynamic dispatch.  Move polymorphism down, removing a level of indirection or two.  Then weeks of profiling and tweaking against realistic data.

Answer (score 0):

In theory, using std::variant and std::visit to implement dynamic polymorphism should not be slower than the implementation based on virtual functions.

In your approach, the lambda function used in the following code

```
if (!std::visit([&](const auto &comp) {
  return comp.comp(i, j);
}, a)) {
  return false;
}
```

repeatedly copies the pointers of i and j in the std::visit function, which is the main reason for the performance difference.